# Deploy a Crystal Report programmatically?

Tags: powershell, crystal-reports

I'm having difficulty finding directions to programmatically deploy a Crystal Reports XI report to the server for general use.  Is there a COM object, Web Service, utility, or something else that can be used to script report deployment?

I will need to do this from PowerShell, but can convert from other available solutions.

Comment: Check this maybe?
http://www.crystalbook.com/crtcr/extras/9/VB_Automation_Server.pdf

Comment: How are you defining "deploy a report"? Where to? Do you have an instance of Crystal Enterprise?

Comment: There is a "report server" of some kind.  During a manual deployment, the users use a combination of the software used to develop the reports, and a web app called Central Management Console (I think).  I want to achieve the same type of "publishing" through a script of our own.

Comment: No I didn't.  I'm still convinced there is a way, but I wasn't able to access the right information to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to create a setup project which deploys your reports as and MSI.

In the properties for the setup project select Crystal Reports. Crystal Reports will now be included and installed along with your reports.

Comment: That's not applicable.  The Crystal Reports server already exists, and is working just fine.  How do I deploy a new report to that existing server in an automated way?